# dynamically create items ons-list-item for a carousel in onsen.ui

Tags: android, jquery, carousel, onsen-ui, listitem

I need to create a carousel onsen like Example http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/emmKpV, I'm trying to dynamically create items ons-list-item but my code is not working, when dynamically insert a new ons-list-item adding the html code in the ons-list, the new ons-list-item are not displayed, my code is as follows:

here my html code.

```
<ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Simple ng-repeat list</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-list id='contenedor'></ons-list>
    <input type='button' value="item" onclick='crearItem()' />
 </ons-page>
```

here my javascript code.

```
function crearItem(){
    htmlText = "<ons-list-item class='list-item'><ons-carousel swipeable class='item-container' initial-index='1' auto-scroll><ons-carousel-item class='list-action-menu' >Borrar</ons-carousel-item><ons-carousel-item class='list-action-item'>title</ons-carousel-item></ons-carousel></ons-list-item>";  
    document.getElementById('contenedor').innerHTML = htmlText;
}
```

here my full code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPNRzX

In advance thank you very much to anyone who can help me

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried to explain my problem editing the question more specifically, I'm not getting any errors, just not displayed the new item I'm trying to create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add content dynamically you need to compile it using the `ons.compile()` function.

In your case it would look something like this:

```
function crearItem(){
  htmlText = "<ons-list-item class='list-item'><ons-carousel swipeable class='item-container' initial-index='1' auto-scroll><ons-carousel-item class='list-action-menu' >Borrar</ons-carousel-item><ons-carousel-item class='list-action-item'>title</ons-carousel-item></ons-carousel></ons-list-item>";  
  var el = document.getElementById('contenedor');
  el.innerHTML = htmlText;
  ons.compile(el);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so I have resolved, here my code:   htmlText = "<ons-list-item class='list-item'><ons-carousel swipeable class='item-container' initial-index='1' auto-scroll><ons-carousel-item class='list-action-menu' >Borrar</ons-carousel-item><ons-carousel-item class='list-action-item'>title</ons-carousel-item></ons-carousel></ons-list-item>";  
    
    var elm = $(htmlText);
    elm.appendTo($("#contenedor")); // Insert to the DOM first
    ons.compile(elm[0]); // The argument must be a HTMLElement object

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not recommended, you don't need to add the HTML directly. Instead, you can do something like this:

```html
<ons-carousel var="carousel" auto-refresh swipeable overscrollable style="height: 50%; width: 100%;" item-width="40%">
  <ons-carousel-item ng-repeat="item in items" ng-attr-style="background-color: {{ item }}">
    {{ item }}   
  </ons-carousel-item>
</ons-carousel>
```

By using `ng-repeat="item in items"` you can repeat the `items` content for all the elements. You can define the content of `items` inside a controller.

Here is a [CopePen example](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/garzJg) about how to create dynamic Carousel content, I hope it helps!